How to configure Skim to always open PDFs in tabs?
How to configure Skim on Sequoia 15.0.1 (24A348) to always open PDFs in tabs?
Executing defaults write -app Skim AppleWindowTabbingMode -string always basically changes nothing, and PDFs open randomly in tabs or in new windows on randomly selected screen.
